# EF calls using Task throws The context cannot be used while the model is being created or The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: entity-framework, task-parallel-library

I am trying to improve performance of a big union clause EF query by calling them using Task class in .NET 4.0. But sometimes Task.WaitAll() throws either context cannot be used while the model is being created or it says the underlying provider failed to open.

Existing EF query

```
//Fetches non saved transaction
        //var edlTransactions = (from edlTran in _context.MarketTransactions.OfType<EDLTransaction>()
        //                       where edlTran.MarketData.Any(m => m.ProfilePoints.Any(p => p.Status != (int)MarketDataState.New && assetProfileIds.Contains(p.AssetProfileID)))
        //                                                select edlTran).OrderByDescending(o => o.LogTime).Take(rowCount);


        //var dataEntryTransactions = (from daTran in _context.MarketTransactions.OfType<EDLDataEntry>()
        //                             where daTran.MarketData.Any(m => m.ProfilePoints.Any(p => p.Status != (int)MarketDataState.New && assetProfileIds.Contains(p.AssetProfileID)))
        //                                                    select daTran).OrderByDescending(o => o.LogTime).Take(rowCount);


        //var nonSavedTransactions = edlTransactions.Cast<MarketTransaction>().Union(dataEntryTransactions).OrderByDescending(o => o.LogTime).Take(rowCount);

        //var utcDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

        ////Fetches saved transactions
        //var edlSavedTransactions = (from edlTran in _context.MarketTransactions.OfType<EDLTransaction>()
        //                            where edlTran.MarketData.Any(m => m.ProfilePoints.Any(p => p.PointTime >= utcDateTime && p.Status == (int)MarketDataState.New && assetProfileIds.Contains(p.AssetProfileID))) && edlTran.AccountId == userId
        //                                               select edlTran);

        ////finally merging non saved status & saved status transactions
        //return nonSavedTransactions.Cast<MarketTransaction>().Union(edlSavedTransactions).ToList().AsQueryable();
```

Updated query using Task

```
            var tasks = new Task[3];
        tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            edlTransactions = (from edlTran in _context.MarketTransactions.OfType<EDLTransaction>()
                where
                    edlTran.MarketData.Any(
                        m =>
                            m.ProfilePoints.Any(
                                p =>
                                    p.Status != (int) MarketDataState.New &&
                                    assetProfileIds.Contains(p.AssetProfileID)))
                select edlTran).OrderByDescending(o => o.LogTime).Take(rowCount).ToList();

        });

        tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            dataEntryTransactions = (from daTran in _context.MarketTransactions.OfType<EDLDataEntry>()
                where
                    daTran.MarketData.Any(
                        m =>
                            m.ProfilePoints.Any(
                                p =>
                                    p.Status != (int) MarketDataState.New &&
                                    assetProfileIds.Contains(p.AssetProfileID)))
                select daTran).OrderByDescending(o => o.LogTime).Take(rowCount).ToList();

        });

        tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var utcDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

            //Fetches saved transactions
            edlSavedTransactions = (from edlTran in _context.MarketTransactions.OfType<EDLTransaction>()
                where
                    edlTran.MarketData.Any(
                        m =>
                            m.ProfilePoints.Any(
                                p =>
                                    p.PointTime >= utcDateTime && p.Status == (int) MarketDataState.New &&
                                    assetProfileIds.Contains(p.AssetProfileID))) && edlTran.AccountId == userId
                select edlTran).ToList();

        });

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same data context concurrently which is not supported. Use a different context for each thread.

Comment: but that's an overhead isn't it & will reduce the performance which defeats the purpose?

Comment: You cannot do what you are doing right now. You *cannot* use a context concurrently, ever.; Compare the overhead of creating a context and issuing a query. Creating it costs almost nothing. Issuing a query is expensive. This should answer your concerns regarding overhead.

Comment: Thanks @usr. One query can I use using block around dataContext like this,  : using(var context = FrameworkEntities.GetDataContext())
                { 
        edlTransactions = (from edlTran in context.MarketTransactions.OfType<EDLTransaction>()
         where
          edlTran.MarketData.Any(
           m =>
            m.ProfilePoints.Any(
             p =>
              p.Status != (int) MarketDataState.New &&
              assetProfileIds.Contains(p.AssetProfileID)))
         select edlTran).OrderByDescending(o => o.LogTime).Take(rowCount).ToList();
                }

Comment: That would be the appropriate way to do it. Make sure that edlTransactions is not shared between threads, though.